# Accessing QComboBox from different class

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 files Gui.cpp, ReadData.cpp (and headers). I need to access the QComboBox member in the Gui.cpp from ReadData.cpp. When I do this, the code compiles fine but when I run my application, it crashes, saying Access Violation . What am I doing wrong ?

How can I access the QComboBox in Gui.cpp from readdata ?

**Gui.h**

```
class Gui : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Gui() {}
        ~Gui() {}
        QComboBox* comboBox;
        ReadData* r;
   private:
        void run();
}
```

**Gui.cpp**

```
void Gui::run()
{
    QWidget *w = new QWidget();

    comboBox = new QComboBox();

    //code...
    r = new ReadData();
    THROW_IF_FALSE(QObject::connect(loadButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), r, SLOT(read())));
 }
```

**readdata.h**

```
class ReadData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ReadData() {}
    ~ReadData() {}

    public slots :
    void read();
private:
    void displayResult(QString arg);
};
```

**readdata.cpp**

```
void ReadData::read()
{
    Gui cb;
    QString str1 = cb.comboBox->currentText();
}
```

Comment: `Gui::comboBox` doesn't appear to ever be initialized anywhere. It's an uninitialized pointer containing random garbage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's actually in Gui.cpp, but I just didn't list it here.

Comment: So you expect everyone to break out their crystal balls and read the actual code from your monitor?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik calm down buddy, i just added it. I didnt think it matters since I'm just trying to learn how to access it from readdata.cpp

Comment: `ReadData::read` never calls `run()` on `cb`. `cb.comboBox` is still an uninitialized pointer containing random garbage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so how can I call it ? Basically I have a button in that calls readdata.cpp to read the data on whatever its in the combobox...

Comment: Well, presumably, you have another instance of `Gui` somewhere in your program, on which you did call `run()` and which did create a combobox. You need to pass a pointer or reference to *that* instance to `ReadData` - e.g. as a parameter in constructor.

Comment: When you write `int x = 42; int y;` you don't expect `y` to magically have the same value as `x`. By the same token, `Gui cb;` local variable doesn't magically acquire the same value as some other `Gui` instance elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I got you.. I'm just thinking how to pass that pointer/reference since I actually use a QSignal slot invoke ReadData.. Appreciate your help sir!

Comment: Which part of "pass as a parameter to constructor" do you find unclear? As in, for example, `r = new ReadData(this);` Adjusting `ReadData` implementation accordingly is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've been reading about passing parameter to constructor but I can't seem to grasp the concept. I appreciate if you could guide me further ! Sorry I'm transitioning to C++ from Python and I'm still learning this. Thanks !

Comment: @Arbitel "I didnt think it matters" You don't know the true source of the bug, perhaps you can't quite tell what's relevant and what's not. That's why you should provide a *complete and minmal compileable example* of the issue. It's also counterproductive to split your trivial code into 4 files. Before including code in the question, you'd best put it into a single `main.cpp`, remove everything irrelevant, and post that. It then allows someone to answer without any back-and-forth. Look [here](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions) for hundreds of examples.